# While-loop skips entries with same meta value

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, duplicates, skip

I have a list of entries and some of them have the same code. For the overview of the entries I need only one of them. I created a while loop with a counter and code value checker which returns the IDs of the entries in an array if there are more entries with the same code ID, and false if there is none, and its works. However, I think there is maybe a better way to do this.

```
        <?php

        $c                   = 0;

        if ( $r->have_posts() ):
            while ( $r->have_posts() ):
                $r->the_post();


                $course_code_id = rp_get_meta( "rp_course_code" );
                if ( rp_meta_value_exists( 'rp_course_code', $course_code_id, $post_type, 'published' ) ) {
                    if ( $c > 1 ) {
                        $c = 0;
                    }
                } else {
                    $c = 0;
                }

                $c ++;

                if ( $c > 1 ) {
                    continue;
                }

                echo rp_get_view( 'courses', 'loop/' . $style, true);

            endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();

        endif;
        ?>
```

Comment: Tag your question with the appropriate language to get more (useful) views and increase the likelihood of getting an answer.

Comment: I don't think this code is working as you describe it in all circumstances. If you have a datanbank with **no duplicates** (e.g. only published posts with unique course ID), it will find the first course and increment c(=1). In the next step, it will put c=2 and not printing the course. I guess you're lucky that there are always enough `drafts` or `duplicates` in between the data set.

Comment: Another example would be a database with posts alternating from ID=1, ID-2, ID=1, ID=2, ... , you would print out only ID=1 entries.